# Symfony twig with subobject

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I do not know if this is a bug in the Symfony/twig or I do not understand this correctly.

I have my form with many field and one 'field' is the subobject (maybe this have something else name, but I do not know how in Symfony notation), like this:

```
...
...
->add('bank_name', TextType::class,
    [
        'required' => false,
        'label' => 'Bank name',
        'attr' => [
            'title' => 'Bank name',
        ],
    ])
->add('person', PersonType::class,
    [
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Contact Person data',
    ])
 ...
 ...
```

This make form in the twig correctly, but when I want to edit my data, `Person` fields are not filled.

I made a `dump` of the form to check what is happened here and I found workaround solution:

`{{ form_widget(form.person.name, {'value': form.person.vars.value.name}) }}`

This is solution because in regular way, values are located in, for example:
`{{ dump(form.bank_name.vars.value) }}`,

but in the Person case it is located in:
`{{ dump(form.person.vars.value.name) }}`, 
`{{ dump(form.person.vars.value.address) }}`, ...

Any hint here?

```
    "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/form": "^4.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.3",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/serializer": "^4.0",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
```

**Edit #1:**

Fill form with data in the Controller:

```
    $bank = Utils::jsonToObject($bankData, Bank::class);
    if (isset($bankData->person)) {
        $person = Utils::jsonToObject($bankData->person, \App\Entity\API\Person::class);
    } else {
        $person = new \App\Entity\API\Person();
    }
    $bank->setPerson($person);

    $form = $this->createForm(BankType::class, $bank);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

**Edit #2**

I have found where is exactly issue, but workaround what I mention before does not work.

Issue is only with `name` Person field. All other fields working properly. I guess it is conflict with `subobject name` - `Person` and `Person field name`

Comment: Can you show how you're building the form in the controller?

Comment: Does personType is a custom type ? If yes, can you show how you made it, the formType and the rendered view of the widget please...